# Clipping the weights by norms in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to constraint the l2 norm of the weight matrices in my DNN. This is how i do it

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
gvs = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_op)
capped_gvs = [(grad, tf.clip_by_norm(var,1, axes = None)) for grad, var in gvs]
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)
```

But on running the code, I get the following error:

> NotImplementedError: ('Trying to optimize unsupported type ', 'train_3/clip_by_norm:0' shape=(200, 256) dtype=float32>)

Answer (score 0):

The type of `capped_gvs` must be:

```
[(<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/Fill:0' shape=(9,) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(9,) dtype=float32_ref>)]
```

Istead of:

```
[(<tf.Tensor 'gradients_1/Fill:0' shape=(9,) dtype=float32>,
  <tf.Tensor 'clip_by_norm:0' shape=(9,) dtype=float32>)]
```

Try to change the `capped_gvs` line in this way:

```
capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_norm(var,1, axes = None),var) for grad, var in gvs]
```